# Identical items removal from lists

Tags: python

beginner python user,
I have to write a function that takes as parameters two lists L1 and L2 and returns a list L3 of elements that are common to L1 and L2. For example: L1=[5,4,6,3,4], L2=[9,4,3,11], then the function returns [4,3] (an element is listed once).
Now, I am able to append the elements (find my code below) which is the easy part, but I can't seem to not include the already appended elements.

```
def common(L1,L2):

   L3=[]
   for i in range (len(L1)):
       for j in range (len(L2)):
          if L1[i]==L2[j]:
             L3.append(L1[i])

L1=[5,4,6,3,4]
L2=[9,4,3,11]
print(common(L1,L2))
```

If I try to include a nested loop for L3 and a condition in the if statement, nothing gets printed.

Comment: `L3 = list(set(L1) & set(L2))`

Comment: And if you want it in order (of L2), you can do `L3 = sorted(list(set(L1) & set(L2)),key = lambda x: L2.index(x))`. (just replace L2 by L1 in the lambda to return it in order of L1)
Unfortunately, i can't post an answer myself because the post is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to check and see if each element in `L1` is in `L2`, but not in `L3`. (It also checks the entire list, so you don't have to write your own nested loop.)

```
L3 = []
for x in L1:
    if x in L2 and x not in L3:
        L3.append(x)
```